# JavaScript input button is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JSP page that looks like below:

[image]

When I click on Edit button, the word `Edit:advance configuration` shows below the current window. Clicking the button a few more times will only trigger to call `editUrl.jsp`.

It looks like below:

[image]

I am really confused as to why it behaves the way it behaved.

This is my function call when I click Edit button:

```
 function editURL(){




                    $('body').pWin("open", {
                        x: 260,
                        y: 47,
                        height: 450,
                        width: 881,
                        title: "Edit:Advance configuration",
                        skinMode:'dialog',
                        iframe:true,
                        url: "editUrl.jsp",
                        data: {





                        },
                        offResize:true,
                        offMove:true,
                        onTitle:false,
                        offBottom:true
                    });




                }
```

And my editUrl.jsp:

```
<head>
    <title>Edit:Advance Configuration</title>

    <%

        String relPath = "../../../";


    %>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=relPath%>js/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=relPath%>js/jquery/jquery-panton-win.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=relPath%>js/jquery/jquery-panton-win-2.js"></script>

    <style>

        body {
            font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size:12px;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        legend {
            font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
            font-size:12pt;
            padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;
        }

        fieldset {
            -moz-border-radius:10px;
            border:1px solid lightgrey;
        }



        label{
            display:block;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:right;
            width:140px;
            float:left;
            font-size:12px;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>


<%out.print("testststs\n");

    out.print("testststs\n");

    out.print("testststs\n");

    out.print("testststs");



%>







</body>
```

Is there anything I did wrong? I just want to click the Edit button,then it should open the same window size and "cover" the current window.

Comment: Can you try unbind() it.

Comment: meaning how it looks?